# What is the meaning of this pun on the word 'lion'

Tags: vocabulaire

This is from Proust:

> (Pour Françoise la comparaison d’un homme à un lion, qu’elle prononçait li-on, n’avait rien de flatteur.)

Maybe this has something to do with 'on lit', i.e. 'one reads' but I still don't see why that wouldn't be flattering.

Comment: Perhaps *Lyon*, the name of a city. Or *lit-on?* - but I am not sure whether pronoun *on* could be used like that in the times of Proust.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want a pun on lions, thank the translators of *The Lion King* who have Scar observe pointedly that "Rebelle et lion font rébellion !"

Answer (score 1):

There is no pun, only a remark about Françoise's mannered pronunciation of ***lion***.

What is unflattering is not her pronunciation but the comparison she makes, and it is unflattering for the men she refers to, the soldiers marching in Combray.

> C’est pourtant vrai qu’ils n’y tiennent pas ! Je les ai vus en 70 ; ils n’ont plus peur de la mort, dans ces misérables guerres ; c’est ni plus ni moins des fous ; et puis ils ne valent plus la corde pour les pendre, ce n’est pas des hommes, c’est des lions.

In her mind, to say that a man is a lion is unflattering because a lion is fierce, lacks humanity, and does not value life. The narrator must explain that this comparison is unflattering because usually such a comparison is positive: a lion is strong and powerful.

Comment: so why is the remark not flattering?

Comment: The narrator's remark about Françoise's pronunciation is relatively neutral. On the other hand, Françoise believes that telling that a man is a lion is unflattering (likely because a lion is wild and cruel) while generally, such comparison is positive (a lion is strong and powerful).

Comment: @bobsmith76 more context would be needed to understand Francoise's state of mind, but that pronunciation can sound overly pedantic or scary on purpose.